# htaccess redirection do wrong page direction

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

this my htaccess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /Songs/Songs\.php\?movie=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^/Songs/%3?%4 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?Songs/(.*)$ /Songs/Songs.php?movie=$1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

It is redirecting perfectly like

From

```
localhost/Songs/Songs.php?movie=anymovie-2012
```

To

```
localhost/Songs/anymovie-2012
```

But when I tried

```
localhost/Songs/<anytext>
```

For eg.

```
localhost/Songs/test
```

then it also called songs.php instead of throwing page not found error.

how to throw Page not Found Error if last keyword is not present in database.

For solution,

should I need to code in songs.php file or in .htaccess file and what type of code I need to do?

Comment: What makes a string valid for redirection? Does it have to follow the format title-year, or are there other rules as far as what is acceptable?

Comment: last value is always in format like "moviename-year-mp3"

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific in your conditions about what format should be redirected; eg

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^[a-z0-9]+\-[0-9]{4}(\-[a-z0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^/?Songs/(.*)$ /Songs/Songs.php?movie=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Should work. The new line requires a title dash year, where the title can only contain lower case letters and numbers and the year must be four numbers, followed by an optional string of letters and numbers.